# ros_serial, arduino, lights on/off with variable delay

Tags: ros, arduino, rosserial, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I was wondering about a project that I wanted to use ROS in a dispensing setup. I have a Python code setup running the pocketsphinx for voice recognition. Everything is working there, I am publishing command words. I know the next step is to create a python code that monitors the command topic and then publishes that to the arduino over ros_serial. I may have over looked it, but I haven't seen much on that step.

In relative terms this seems pretty easy. I just want to be able to turn a 5v solenoid on for a variable amount of time. I say what solenoid and then the amount of time. Then that info is sent to the arduino. So I was thinking it sounded a lot like the blinking light on the ros_serial tutorial as I was going through it. The thing that got me was how to load a variable number into a variable delay timer. I want the solenoid to stay on, not blink. Where would I set the delay, right after each callback or in void_loop? I thought that I could give each CallBack its own identifier and thats how I would identify the solenoids, I don't know if thats right or not.

If anybody knows a direction to look, that would be great.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31050/ros_serial,-arduino,-lights-on/off-with-variable-delay/) by [matt2027](https://answers.ros.org/users/2108/matt2027/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-04-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please go through the tutorials ... take a look at [publish/subscribers for python](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29) that should be what you want. Also please try to make your questions clear and only one question per post so we can mark them closed when answered ... I was not sure what you were asking.

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1